# First day of the month from a POSIXct date time using lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

Given a POSIXct date time, how do you extract the first day of the month for aggregation?

```
library(lubridate)

full.date <- ymd_hms("2013-01-01 00:00:21")
```

Comment: I know one way to do it, hopefully there are some smarter ways out there.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

[lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/) has a function called `floor_date` which rounds date-times down. Calling it with `unit = "month"` does exactly what you want:

```
library(lubridate)
full.date <- ymd_hms("2013-01-01 00:00:21")
floor_date(full.date, "month")

[1] "2013-01-01 UTC"
```

Comment: Could we remove the tz?

Comment: @ay__ya try `lubridate::as_date`

Answer (score 31):

I don't see a reason to use lubridate:

```
full.date <- as.POSIXct("2013-01-11 00:00:21", tz="GMT")

monthStart <- function(x) {
  x <- as.POSIXlt(x)
  x$mday <- 1
  as.Date(x)
}

monthStart(full.date)
#[1] "2013-01-01"
```

Comment: +1 for not using a string formatting hack (like me).

Comment: Just came across this, nice way of going about it. Makes it really easy, was over complicating it also with lubridate.

Comment: This is also significantly faster.

Answer (score 15):

```
first.of.month <- ymd(format(full.date, "%Y-%m-01"))
first.of.month

[1] "2013-01-01 UTC"
```

Answer (score 2):

i have another solution :

```
first.of.month <- full.date - mday(full.date) + 1
```

but it needs the library 'lubridate' or 'date.table' (aggregation with data.table)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use base R's `trunc`:

```r
d <- as.POSIXct("2013-01-11 00:00:21", tz="UTC")
trunc(d, "month")
#[1] "2013-01-01 UTC"
```