# How to change x axis from years to months with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a web visits over time chart which plots daily traffic from 2014 until now, and looks like this:

```
 ggplot(subset(APRA, Post_Day > "2013-12-31"), aes(x = Post_Day, y = Page_Views))+
   geom_line()+
   scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)+
   ylim(0,50000)
```

[image]

As you can see it's not a great graph, what would make a bit more sense is to break it down by month as opposed to day. However when I try this code:

```
 ggplot(subset(APRA, Post_Day > "2013-12-31"), aes(x = Post_Day, y = Page_Views))+
   geom_line()+
   scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)+
   ylim(0,50000)+
   scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", minor_breaks = "1 week", labels = date_format("%B"))
```

I get this error:

> Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

The date field `Post_Day` is `POSIXct`. `Page_Views` is numeric. Data looks like:

```
Post_Title  Post_Day    Page_Views
Title 1     2016-05-15  139
Title 2     2016-05-15  61
Title 3     2016-05-15  79
Title 4     2016-05-16  125
Title 5     2016-05-17  374
Title 6     2016-05-17  39
Title 7     2016-05-17  464
Title 8     2016-05-17  319
Title 9     2016-05-18  84
Title 10    2016-05-18  64
Title 11    2016-05-19  433
Title 12    2016-05-19  418
Title 13    2016-05-19  124
Title 14    2016-05-19  422
```

I'm looking to change the X axis from a daily granularity into monthly.

Comment: Isn't this really a question about how to aggregate dates into months, rather than how to change the x axis?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 yes I suppose so. I thought that's what I was doing with `scale_x_date()` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: The use of `Post_Day > "2013-12-31"` indicates that Post_Day is a character variable. You should convert this variable to a date class using `as.Date` Then you'd use `Post_Day > as.Date("2013-12-31")`.

Comment: you could create columns for `year(post_day)` and `month(post_day)` or you could use one of [these approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602706/first-day-of-the-month-from-a-posixct-date-time-using-lubridate) to take the "month floor" of the date

Comment: @lmo R is smart enough to handle the comparison  `Post_Day > "2013-12-31"` when `Post_Day` is a `Date`

Comment: @Imo thanks for the suggestion however it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample data set shown in the question has multiple data points per day. So, it needs to be aggregated day-wise anyway. For the aggregation by day or month, `data.table` and `lubridate` are used.

#### Create sample data

As no reproducible example is supplied, a sample data set is created:

```
library(data.table)
n_rows <- 5000L
n_days <- 365L*3L
set.seed(123L)
DT <- data.table(Post_Title = paste("Title", 1:n_rows),
                 Post_Day = as.Date("2014-01-01") + sample(0:n_days, n_rows, replace = TRUE),
                 Page_Views = round(abs(rnorm(n_rows, 500, 200))))[order(Post_Day)]
DT
```

> ```
>       Post_Title   Post_Day Page_Views
>    1:   Title 74 2014-01-01        536
>    2:  Title 478 2014-01-01        465
>    3: Title 3934 2014-01-01        289
>    4: Title 4136 2014-01-01        555
>    5:  Title 740 2014-01-02        442
>   ---                                 
> 4996: Title 1478 2016-12-31        586
> 4997: Title 2251 2016-12-31        467
> 4998: Title 2647 2016-12-31        468
> 4999: Title 3243 2016-12-31        498
> 5000: Title 4302 2016-12-31        309
> ```

#### Plot raw data

Without aggregation the data can be plotted by

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DT) + aes(Post_Day, Page_Views) + geom_line()
```

[image]

#### Aggregated by day

```
ggplot(DT[, .(Page_Views = sum(Page_Views)), by = Post_Day]) + 
  aes(Post_Day, Page_Views) + geom_line()
```

To aggregate day-wise the grouping parameter `by` of `data.table` is used and `sum()` as aggregation function. The aggregation is reducing the number of data points from 5000 to 1087. Hence, the plot looks less convoluted.

[image]

#### Aggregated by month

```
ggplot(DT[, .(Page_Views = sum(Page_Views)), 
          by = .(Post_Month = lubridate::floor_date(Post_Day, "month"))]) + 
  aes(Post_Month, Page_Views) + geom_line()
```

In order to aggregate by month, the grouping parameter `by` is used but this time `Post_Day` is mapped to the first day of the respective months. So, `2014-03-26` becomes a `Post_Month` of `2014-03-01` which is still of class `POSIXct`. By this, the x-axis remains continuous with a date scale. This avoids the trouble when converting `Post_Day` to factor, e.g, `"2014-03"` using `format(Post_Day, ""%Y-%m")`, where the x-axis would become discrete.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure this is the correct solution to the problem. Sounds like the question is about changing the labels on the axis, not aggregating the data. ggplot2::scale_x_date also has scale_x_datetime options - having the posixct date as a date-time rather than a date would give the error shown, and is easily fixed by changing scale_x_date to scale_x_datetime

Comment: @LucieCBurgess Using `scale_x_datetime()` instead of `scale_x_date()` will make the error message go away but will *not* solve the underlying problem. The misunderstanding is that changing the scale to month would automatically aggregate the data by month as well - which it does not.  In OP's words *As you can see it's not a great graph, what would make a bit more sense is to break it down by month as opposed to day.* OP's data contain multiple entries per day which need to be aggregated by day, anyway. Apparently, the OP was happy with my answer and has accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

```
APRA$month <- as.factor(stftime(APRA$Post_Day, "%m")
APRA       <- APRA[order(as.numeric(APRA$month)),]
```

This would create a month column to your data

```
z <- apply(split(APRA, APRA$month), function(x) {sum(as.numeric(APRA$Page_Views))})
z <- do.call(rbind, z)
z$month <- unique(APRA$month)
colnames(Z) <- c("Page_Views", "month")
```

This would create a `z` `dataframe` which has months and page views each month

Now plot it

```
ggplot(z, aes(x = month, y = Page_Views)) + geom_line()
```

Please let me know if this is what you were looking for. Also I haven't compiled it, please tell if it throws some error.